# issue with php $diff->format

Tags: php, intervals

I get a `"Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object in /home/mrbits/public_html/tickets/index2.php on line 407"` with the following code:

```
Xxx
Xxxx
xxxx
..
$t_enter=$row['fecha_ing'];   <- fields is type DATE
$yesterday=strtotime($t_enter);
$today_is = date("Y/m/d");
$diff=date_diff($yesterday,$today_is);
$t_elapsed= $diff->format("%y A %m m %d d");     <--- HERE's the ERROR
?>

<td><?php echo $t_idticket; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $t_elapsed; ?></td>
```

What can be wrong? The type of variable in the date of table?

Answer (score 0):

You have a type mismatch. `$yesterday` is an integer while `$today_is` is a string. You have to perform a `strtotime($today_is);` as the `$date_diff();` expects 2 `DateTime` objects so you'll need an extra conversion.

Comment: tnx Burimi i knew it must be something about the data types.. i didnt knew about the date_create function.. really tnx

Answer (score 0):

Use [date_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create.php):

```
$t_enter=$row['fecha_ing'];  
$yesterday=date_create($t_enter);
$today_is = date_create(date("Y/m/d"));
$diff=date_diff($yesterday,$today_is);
$t_elapsed= $diff->format("%y A %m m %d d");
```